# access to model.Id on razor view page from javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

on view page I have and inside javascript code I want to access to my Model.Id. How this can be done?

```
@model MyModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
       var id = model.Id // this doesnt work
    }
</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep track of what's on the server and what's on the client.  The `@Model` variable is only used on the server, Javascript has no notion of the model object, so you need to print the values out in the html.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
       var id = "@Model.Id"; // this will work
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. Still need to use the razor syntax..`@`.

```
@model MyModel
<script type="text/javascript">
    function initialize() {
       var id = "@Model.Id" // this doesnt work
    }
</script>
```

Comment: this may cause a javascript error depending on the value of @Model.Id - specifically if it's NaN.

Answer (score 1):

Make model.id to "@Model.id" Like :

```
@model MyModel
<script type="text/javascript">
function initialize() {
   var id = "@Model.Id"
}
</script>
```